# Matched filter for recieved RF digital packet by LPF

Tags: matlab, digital-communications, noise, signal-detection, preamble

Im transmitting by cc1350 launchpad microprocessor digital RF Packets, transmitted modulation FSK. bit rate of transmitting is  50Kbouad, frequency of transmitting is 868MHZ . Im sampling the signal(RF PACKETS) that Im transmitting by a dongle SDR-RTL and it samples on frequency 2048000Hz , I want to decode the RF packets that Im transmitting, so I build demodulator and I see the data of my RF packet which it's: (I plot it in matlab plot)

[image]

So if you see here on the plot it shows data of my sampled RF packet, and in order to decode it to 0/1 (binary), I want to do LPF in order to smooth/smear much more my received Rf packet "to look like smoothly sinusoidal"

any help how can I do that?

I mean by demodulator is that I've done two matched filters (Mf1, MF2) as I shown in the photo below:
[image]

Comment: what does that plot show, exactly? What is the y and the x axis? (because: if this is the time domain signal, this very much isn't FSK.)

Comment: shows the entire packet data , y is amplitude and x is time! it's GFSK modulation. my demodulator is demodulation of FSK signal this means that the received signal is FSK signal

Comment: Well, the signal you've plotted is clearly not FSK, sorry.

Comment: I will try to plot another plot to be more clear, I will attach on the same thread

Comment: what I attached above is the output of my demodulator yeah? not the IQ raw data that I received

Comment: then y isn't amplitude. What does your demodulator do? What kind of demodulator is it?

Comment: I updated my thread, I explained what I mean by demodulator .. I mean two matched filter

Comment: aaaaah that makes sense!

Comment: if there's any other question, Im here to answer you !

Comment: So Im stuck, I want to do LPF in order to make my signal more smoothly and to do zero crossings in order to choose when I have 0 and 1 in binary

Comment: but I dont know what cut off frequency to put my LPF, and how should I do LPF in matlab? Im using dongle sdr-rtl , my sampling frequency is 2048Khz , bitrate is 300Khz , transmitted frequency is 868Mhz

Answer (score -1):

Well, you know that the output of your filters shouldn't change faster than a symbol period. You could low-pass filter these to a bandwidth only a bit bigger than the symbol rate.

Since a filter is a linear operation, you can commute it and have it *before* the matched filters, so you only need one low-pass filter.

> smoothly and to do zero crossings in order to choose when I have 0 and 1 in binary

Don't. You should be using a threshold instead of going by zero crossings: the zero is your maximum likelihood decision boundary.

You'll need symbol timing recovery, anyways. Since this is a bursty system, not an "endless" stream of symbols, I'd guess the packet preamble is probably meant to give you that information – use it!

If you can correctly estimate symbol timing from the preamble, your Matched Filters can be coherently decimating down to the symbol rate.

Comment: but I really understand you, I used zero as threshold which if my packet data above zero then 1 in binary, otherwise 0 in binary but Im not seeing the bits that I've transmitted .. so! Im clarifying that the output of my demodulator I made the condition that if bigger than zero then 1 otherwise then 0 but I didn't succeed to see my syncword or preamble bits

Comment: I didn't try to use Low pass filter before two matching filter once I use threshold 0 (maybe that's the problem).... how can I do my LPF in matlab and at which frequency cut off? bitrate?

Comment: Matlab has a filter design tool.

Comment: yes Im using it, but I need for instance several things, once is cut off frequency of my LPF , passbandRipple, Sample Rate, the order of my LPF .

Comment: Since Im using smartRFstudio 7 that I can configure the parametrs of transmitting. at which more preferable to put my bit rate frequency, deviation frequency? as shown in my photo above I put my bit rate 300Kboud , deviation 150Khz. Im ofcourse sampling at 2048kHz. thanks for your help

Comment: this is what filter design tool request: (matlab code) dsp.LowpassFilter('SampleRate',Fs,...
    'DesignForMinimumOrder',false,'FilterOrder',N,...
    'PassbandFrequency',Fp,'PassbandRipple',Ap,'StopbandAttenuation',Ast); and in my case I don't know which parameters to input to my LPF according to my case

Comment: I said that the bandwidth of the filter needs to be only slightly higher than the symbol rate, so that gives you your cut off frequency. The rest is up to your design (which I won't be doing for you in the comments, lacking any information about your system). This requires more work on your part!

Comment: I understand you're right! , may I ask another question? so what I want to do right now is LPF and then doing my two matched filter on the output of my LPF! , so afterwards there's no need to do zero-crossings and it's enough to choose zero as threshold and if my data values bigger than zero then mapping it to 1 in binary, otherwise 0 in binary ..so I would get bits 0/1 ! now if I want to find in that binary data my preamble, should I search in my transmitted preamble or the transmitted preamble with the bit rate?

Comment: I mean for instance if I sent my preamble as 010101 before transmitting , so at the receiver my preamble would be 01010101  or preamble related to bit-rate? this means that it might be bit before transmitted multiplied by 5times, I mean 0 => 00000 , 1=>11111 so my preamble at receiver would be 000001111100000111110000011111 , (the times that should I multiple my value of bit before transmitting is 1/(bitrate)  right?) .  thanks for your help

Comment: why Im asking this ? because after I make the threshold (zero) condition to get binary bits, I want to search for instance for preamble, and I need to understand how my preamble is shown on the receiver as  "
Replicated" or it's as before transmitting without zero/one replicated according to bitrate.  thanks for your help

Comment: Again, can't help you design a system in the comments. Research, and ask a new question.

Comment: but @Marcus Müller  here is my problem! I exactly done before the threshold method "zero" .. but didn't work why? because I searched for my preamble as what I transmitted before without taking into account bitrate consideration. then I tried to take bitrate consideration meaning by this replicating zero/1 before transmitting of my preamble to factor of my bitrate and still didn't work! so Im asking you if you could help me about that, or actually what should I search since I have binary data, search for my original preamble without bitrate consideration at the receiver or not ..